# How to check the type of an object in TypeScript when it has multiple return type?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a method which has multiple return types. Here, one type is array and the remaining all are single object. I want to a check if the return type is an array then use loop else not.

I can detect array type by using `as` but when I add `if..else` condition, then I am getting `// Getting Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'output1Model | output2Model | output3Model[]'. Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'output1Model'.` error.

Why it is targeting `output1Model` even though return type is indicating all three?

**CODE:**

Service.ts

```
myFunction(input: someModel): output1Model | output2Model | output3Model[] {
    // Some logic. 
   // Return type would be either of these 3 based on condition.
}
```

controller.ts

```
const checkThis = Service.myFunction(input);

// ERROR: Getting Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'output1Model | output2Model | output3Model[]'.
// Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'output1Model'.
if (checkThis as output3Model[]) {
    checkThis.forEach(element => {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
} else {
     // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: Do something like `if (checkThis instanceof Array) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions here:

- `checkThis as output3Model[]` is not *detecting whether* `checkThis` is an `output3Model[]`, it is [*asserting*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that it is one.  Put another way: you are *telling* the compiler, not *asking* it.
- type assertions only have affects on the expression they are used in and do not propagate to subsequent uses of the asserted variable.  So while you could write `(checkThis as output3Model[]).forEach(...)` to narrow the perceived type of `checkThis`   so that the compiler doesn't complain, you cannot write `(checkThis as output3Model[])` and then later `checkThis.forEach()`.  The second use of `checkThis` is not narrowed.  If you want "check and persist" behavior, you need to make use of [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010).  Otherwise you'd have to keep asserting for every use of `checkThis`.
- a type assertion is only a way to communicate with the compiler about what types you expect to see.  It is part of the static type system, and is therefore [*erased*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.  Your code above ends up running in JavaScript as something like:

  ```
  if (checkThis) {
    checkThis.forEach(element => {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
  }
  ```

  As such, you can see that all you are doing to "detect" the type of `checkThis` is making sure it isn't [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).  Presumably `output1Model` and `output2Model` are some objects and therefore not falsy, so this check will *always* try running `checkThis.forEach()` even if `checkThis` does not have a `forEach()` method.  You need a *runtime check*, not a *type system artifact*.

---

All that means that the compiler is treating `checkThis` as the original type `output1Model | output2Model | output3Model[]`, and it complains that since it doesn't know for sure that it has a `forEach()` method, it is not safe to try to call it.

The answer "Why it is targeting `output1Model` even though return type is indicating all three?" has to do with the way the error messages in TypeScript are generated.  If you have a value `v` of type `A | B | C | D | E | F` and you try to use it in a way that is only applicable to `A`, the compiler *could* generate a list of five error messages like "`v` *might* be an `B`, and if so, you can't do what you're doing." and "Or `v` *might* be a `C`, and if so, you can't do what you're doing." and so on up to "Finally, `v` *might* be an `F`, and if so, you can't do what you're doing".  But really, any one of those error messages is enough to tell you you're making a mistake.  So it just picks the first one it comes to.  The fact that `v` might be a `B` is enough to generate the warning about why `B` doesn't let you do what you're trying to do.

---

Summing up, you need to use a runtime check which the compiler can analyze to verify that you are treating `checkThis` like an array only when it is sure to be one.  There are a few ways to do this.

My advice would be `Array.isArray()`, whose [type signature in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f7212aa11966f4d1c09f50165a0c7842162646cf/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1399) is that of a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  If `Array.isArray(checkThis)` returns `true` at runtime, then the compiler knows than any subsequent use of `checkThis` in the control flow can be treated as an array, and thus an `output3Model[]`.  And if it returns `false`, then the compiler knows it is *not* an array, and thus must be an `output1Model | output2Model` (assuming those are not array types):

```
if (Array.isArray(checkThis)) {
  checkThis.forEach(element => {
    // (parameter) element: output3Model
  });
} else {
  checkThis
  // const checkThis: output1Model | output2Model
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you should ensure that your `checkThis` is an array in another way, something like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(checkThis)) {
    checkThis.forEach(element => {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
} else {
     // DO SOMETHING
}
```